# How can I create a simplified twig replacement with PHP?

Tags: php

I want to avoid using  tags in my views. However, I'm struggling with loading my header and footer files as they get outputted as text instead of PHP processing the require_once 'file'. I understand why it's happening, I just don't know how to make it work.

**controller/home.php**

```
<?php

$params = [
   'page_title' => 'My Page Title'
];

renderView('/views/home.view.php', $params);
```

**functions.php**

```
function renderView($view, array $params = []): void
{
    $template = file_get_contents($view, FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);

    foreach($params as $key => $value)
    {
        $template = str_replace('{{ ' . $key . ' }}', $value, $template);
    }

    echo $template;
}
```

**/views/home.view.php**

```
<?php require_once('header.view.php'); ?>

<main>Main content.</main>

<?php require_once('footer.view.php'); ?>
```

**/views/header.view.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>{{ page_title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your header and footer to be subject to tag replacement, then you'll need to output them via the `renderView()` function, not via direct `require_once`. I.e., remove the references to the header/footer from the home view:

```php
<main>Main content.</main>
```

And move them to the home controller:

```php
renderView('/views/header.view.php', $params);
renderView('/views/home.view.php', $params);
renderView('/views/footer.view.php', $params);
```

You have to be careful though, you don't want to have PHP source and replaceable tags in the same file. So, you should probably *not* name your views ending with `*.php`.

Comment: That's a good idea, I'll rename it to .view without the PHP extension.